# React Native webview routing

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, react-router

I'm building a React-Native app with some native screens, and some screens where I load the website with a WebView. Instead of the classical website navigation, I have a native drawer to switch pages.
My issue is that the website is using react-router, so it handles the URL change smoothly on browsers by loading only the necessary code. Still, when I change the URL in my WebView, it does as if I was refreshing the website, and it reloads everything, leading up to very slow navigation.

The only 'hack' I thought would be exposing a function on the website `window` variable to trigger a react-router 'go to'.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Did you ever find a workaround to routing in the WebView for local webapps?

Comment: For me, it magically works for an older app that uses a ConnectedRouter from 'react-router-redux' with browerHistory from 'history' v4 & 'react-router' v4. However, as I upgraded the stack & removed redux altogether, for an app with BrowserRouter from 'react-router' v5 it does not work anymore. The ReactNative app is the same in both cases (exact same version of webview & RN). Would really love to know how to work this around the new app...

Answer (score 2):

So, after a few days of struggling, I have settled with the following solution, which I admit is slighlty obscure, but works perfectly (incl. back button, gestures):

In the **React Web Application**, I keep the ReactRouter history object available through the global Window object.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'
// ...

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ReactRouterHistory: ReturnType<typeof useHistory>
  }
}

const AppContextProvider = props => {
  const history = useHistory()

  // provide history object globally for use in Mobile Application
  window.ReactRouterHistory = history

  // ...
}
```

In the **React Native Mobile Application**, I have custom code injected to the WebView, that makes use of the history object for navigation and the application communicates with this code using messages:

`webViewScript.ts`

```
// ...
export default `
  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    var message = JSON.parse(event.data)
    switch (message.type) {
      // ...
      case '${MessageTypes.NAVIGATE}':
        if (message.params.uri && message.params.uri.match('${APP_URL}') && window.ReactRouterHistory) {
          const url = message.params.uri.replace('${APP_URL}', '')
          window.ReactRouterHistory.push(url)
        }
        break
    }
  };

  !(() => {
    function sendMessage(type, params) {
      var message = JSON.stringify({type: type, params: params})
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message)
    }

    if (!window.appListenersAdded) {
      window.appListenersAdded = true;
    
      window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage)
      
      var originalPushState = window.history.pushState
      window.history.pushState = function () {
        sendMessage('${MessageTypes.PUSH_STATE}', {state: arguments[0], title: arguments[1], url: arguments[2]})
        originalPushState.apply(this, arguments)
      }

    }
  })()
  true
`
```

`intercom.ts` (no routing specifics here, just for generic communication)

```
import WebView, {WebViewMessageEvent} from 'react-native-webview'
import MessageTypes from './messageTypes'


export const sendMessage = (webview: WebView | null, type: MessageTypes, params: Record<string, unknown> = {}) => {
  const src = `
  window.postMessage('${JSON.stringify({type, params})}', '*')
  true // Might fail silently per documentation
  `
  if (webview) webview.injectJavaScript(src)
}

export type Message = {
  type?: MessageTypes,
  params?: Record<string, unknown>
}

export type MessageHandler = (message: Message) => void

export const handleMessage = (handlers: Partial<Record<MessageTypes, MessageHandler>>) => (
  (event: WebViewMessageEvent) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data) as Message
    const messageType = message.type

    if (!messageType) return
    const handler = handlers[messageType]
  
    if (handler) handler(message)
  }
)

export {default as script} from './webViewScript'
```

`WebViewScreen.tsx`

```
import {handleMessage, Message, script, sendMessage} from '../intercom'
// ...

const WebViewScreen = ({navigation, navigationStack}: WebViewScreenProps) => {
  const messageHandlers = {
    [MessageTypes.PUSH_STATE]: ({params}: Message) => {
      if (!params) return
      const {url} = params
      const fullUrl = `${APP_URL}${url}`
      navigationStack.push(fullUrl)
    },
    // ...
  }

  const uri = navigationStack.currentPath

  // navigation solution using history object propagated through window object
  useEffect(() => {
    if (uri) {
      sendMessage(webViewRef.current, MessageTypes.NAVIGATE, {uri})
    }
  }, [uri])

  // this is correct! Source is never going to be updated, navigation is done using native history object, see useEffect above
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  const source = useMemo(() => ({uri}), [])

  return (
    <View
        // ...
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
              // ...
          />
        }
    >
      <WebView
          source={source}
          injectedJavaScript={script}
          onMessage={handleMessage(messageHandlers)}
          // ...
      />
    </View>
  )

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a combination of
`UseEffect` and `route navigation`?

Comment: Please give more details. Effect where & with what code? What is `route navigation` specifically?

Comment: you can use route navigation to switch page, you can read the documentation there https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating and with using UseEffect you can doing something when there is a change (example when true to false, you can do something).

Comment: I don't think that you understand the question fully. This is about interaction between two React applications using a WebView.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30735683)